# Only change the quantity when product already exists in database

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with some kind of 'webshop' I'm building
I add some products in the database but I want to only change the quantity when the product already exists.

I only don't know how to achieve this. Can somebody maybe help me with a function to check if the product already exists so I can add a +1 to ['aantal'] everytime I add a product that already exists?

the post is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-bonbon'])){
    $postGewicht = $_POST['gewicht']; 
    $bonbonName = $_POST['product'];
    $image = $_POST['afbeelding'];
    $quantity = $_POST['aantal'];

    $jsonData = unserialize($_SESSION['json_data']);


    if(count($jsonData,1) >= 1){
        $jsonData['bonbons'][] = array('gewicht' => $postGewicht,'name' => $bonbonName,'afbeelding' => $image, 'aantal' => $quantity);
    } else { 
        $bonbonsArray[] = array('gewicht' => $postGewicht,'name' => $bonbonName,'afbeelding' => $image, 'aantal' => $quantity); 
        $order = array('userId' => $bonbonUser, 'bonbons' => $bonbonsArray);
        $jsonData = $order;
    }

    $_SESSION['json_data'] = serialize($jsonData);
    $orderData = $_SESSION['json_data'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CMS_bonbonOrder WHERE userId='$bonbonUser'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE CMS_bonbonOrder SET jsonData='$orderData' WHERE userId='$bonbonUser';");
}
```

So I put a Json string in the database that looks like this for example:

```
Array
(
    [bonbons] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [gewicht] => 16
                    [name] => test
                    [afbeelding] => amarena%2020g1.jpg
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [gewicht] => 16
                    [name] => test
                    [afbeelding] => amarena%2020g1.jpg
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [gewicht] => 16
                    [name] => test
                    [afbeelding] => amarena%2020g1.jpg
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [gewicht] => 18
                    [name] => Testbonbon 2
                    [afbeelding] => bresil%2017g1.jpg
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [gewicht] => 16
                    [name] => test
                    [afbeelding] => amarena%2020g1.jpg
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I really hope I made myself clear enough!

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? What isn't working?

Comment: There should be a product id, and use it like `select * from CMS_bonbonOrder where id='{the product id}';` to check if product exist. id exist, use `Update`

Comment: You could have made a simple productExist() function in php to return boolean value before executing the update query to update the price...

Comment: Sorry Epodax, my question was not clear indeed. I edited my question.